# Detect invalid credentials being passed to c3p0 connection pool

Tags: java, connection-pooling, c3p0

I'm writing a program that does some stuff on the database. Users are allowed to configure db processes, by passing db host port, type and credentials. It all works fine when values are correct. But when user passes invalid credentials I would like to show an error. So here is the part where I create my connection pool

```
ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
cpds.setJdbcUrl( connectionUrl );
cpds.setUser(username);
cpds.setPassword(password);
```

And later to verify if all is ok with the connection I do

```
cpds.getConnection()
```

I would expect to get some SQLException with vendor specific error saying that credentials are invalid (which happens when you use typical DriverManager way of getting the connection), but instead the process waits until a connection checkout exception is thrown

```
java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:77)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:690)
....
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@20014b8 -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1467)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:644)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:554)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:758)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:685)
    ... 66 more
```

How can I identify that there is a invalid credential issue with c3p0?

Comment: Make dedicated connection only for purpose of testing credentials without connection pooling.

Comment: @rkosegi Indeed that is what I did. Please make your comment as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: just posted as answer. Glad if it helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best way to validate provided credentials/JDBC params is to avoid connection pool at all.

Open dedicated connection just for this purpose and try to execute simplest SQL against new connection (eg `SELECT 1` or similar).
After success, you can pass them to C3P0 otherwise propagate error back to user.

Answer (score 1):

JDBC providers are free to create whatever error/exception messages they want. So you need to be ready to parse the error message of each provider in order to make sense of what is happening.

You can also try to get information from exception types **if** the JDBC provider segregates errors in separate types.

As a side note, giving too much information regarding why the connection failed may be considered a security breach. So one should not expect the JDBC driver to give you such information. For instance, why would any database collaborate with invasion attempts by saying "the username is correct, but the password is not."?

Comment: I am ready to parse the vendor exception messages, I already had this functionality. Now I'm moving from single connection to connection pool and I want to keep the existing error messages - I will not say that password is not ok, just that credentials are not ok. I need to inform the user that the configuration failed because of his input, not because of some other problem (like db not reachable)

Comment: @Nadir This is not what I meant. My point is that **the JDBC driver** will probably not give you a detailed information. So in the general case you will simply have no way to figure out what happened.

Comment: Akira, the driver itself not, but this can be deducted from the exception throwed when you call DriverManager.getConnection(), ie for oracle you will get specialized ORA-xxx wrong credentials in the cause of the error. I did what @rkosegi suggested in his comment

Comment: Sure, C3P0 may obscure things, but opening a new connection to the database also has consequences. Connection pools exist for a reason. You may end up creating too many connections to the DB and then start having problems with those connections. It looks like you don't want the connection pool that your app server gives you and instead you want to create your own structure.

Comment: I never said that I'm running my app in the server of any kind